# Cron format, definition of H in .yml file

Tags: jenkins, regression-testing

I am a beginner in software testing.

I was going through the `.yml` file used to schedule the regression runs and came across this:

```
schedule: "H 1 * * 1,4"
```

I know about cron format, but what I can not figure out is what is the "H" denoting here, surely it is not every minute (0-59) or else simply a '*' would have sufficed.

Could anyone give a bit of explanation here?

Comment: See the "Non-standard characters" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron.

Answer (score 5):

H stands for Hash

> H ( H ) 'H' is used in the Jenkins continuous integration system to
>   indicate that a "hashed" value is substituted. Thus instead of '20 * *
>   * *' which means at 20 minutes after the hour every hour,
>
> 'H * * * *' indicates that the task is performed every hour at an unspecified but
>   invariant time. This allows spreading out tasks over time
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Other reads:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383778/spread-load-evenly-by-using-h-rather-than-5